# Does IE9 Developer preview (Build 4, v1.9.7.9.16.6000) support the File API?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-9, fileapi

Does the latest IE9 Developer preview (Build 4, v1.9.7.9.16.6000) support the file API? The file API I am referring to is: http://www.w3.org/TR/file-upload/

[Caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/) says the support is [uknown](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28HTML5%29#Related_specifications) says it is not supported but doesn't specify what version of Trident it is referring to.

Unfortunately I don't have a windows machine with Vista or 7 on to test at the moment..

Comment: Voted to close as this answer will be outdated by the next preview, and entirely irrelevant after final release.

Comment: Updated to be more specific version-wise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [File API test from Mark Pilgrim's page](http://diveintohtml5.info/everything.html) I got a `false`, sanity checked in Firefox 4.0 nightly and Google Chrome 6.0.490.1 dev and both returned `true`.

Note that [Modernizr.js](http://www.modernizr.com/) doesn't appear to work in IE9 build 4, so it could be the detection script is inaccurate.

Comment: Thanks, I can also confirm that this build does not support it. I managed to test it last night.